# Aggregate functions over array columns

Tags: postgresql, aggregate-functions

Given a table with a column containing `double precision[]` with a fixed/same size.
I am able to fetch an element wise aggregation for min and max:

```sql
select min(array_col) from table;
select max(array_col) from table;
```

The result should be again a `double precision[]` of the same size. If I want to use `avg()` or `stddev()` I get an error message like:

```
function stddev(double precision[]) does not exists
```

The same happens for `avg()`. Is there any work around?

Comment: The `min` and `max` you show are *not* element-wise.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`unnest()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-array.html#id-1.5.8.25.6.2.2.17.1.1.1) to open up the array and work on its elements: [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/njsjPBdhZvP9ifcUkuCRrG/2)

```sql
select avg(el) from (select unnest(array_col) el from test) a;
select stddev(el) from (select unnest(array_col) el from test) a;
```

This will take an average of all elements of all arrays. To get a separate average for each array, differentiate them by primary key (or add some unique id using [`row_number()over()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-window.html#FUNCTIONS-WINDOW-TABLE)) and use a [`group by`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tutorial-agg.html):

```sql
select id,
       avg(el),
       stddev(el)
from (select row_number()over() as id, 
             unnest(array_col) el 
      from test) a 
group by id;
```

Be aware that `min()` used the way you did doesn't pick the least element in each array, or from all arrays combined, or the array with the least sum of values but rather selects the first array according to default array order - in this case it's empty first, value of subsequent elements ascending, `null` last. Similar applies to `max()`. To get the least/greatest element or sum of elements from all arrays, use `min()`/`max()` like in the first example, or the second to get one from each array.

---

### Element wise part

If you don't mind addressing by hand:

```sql
select ARRAY[min(array_col[1]), min(array_col[2])] from test;
```

But you can also leave listing the subscripts to a [`generate_series()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-srf.html) and [`array_upper()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-array.html#id-1.5.8.25.6.2.2.14.1.1.1): [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/IBGJMuei)

```sql
select array_agg(el_min) 
from (select n,min(array_col[ n ]) el_min 
      from test, lateral generate_series(1,array_upper(array_col,1)) as g(n)
      group by n 
      order by n
   ) a;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `unnest` to unpack the array, then apply the aggregate function. Assuming all arrays have three elements, that could be

```
SELECT ARRAY[
          stddev(u.e) FILTER (WHERE n = 1),
          stddev(u.e) FILTER (WHERE n = 2),
          stddev(u.e) FILTER (WHERE n = 3)
       ]
FROM tab
   CROSS JOIN LATERAL unnest(tab.array_col) WITH ORDINALITY AS u(e,n);
```

A better data model would not store this as an array, but as three columns.

Comment: Thanks to all the poster. I agree with having a better data model would be nice.